# Is KVC possible with Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, key-value-coding, caemittercell

I'm trying to create the equivalent of the following Objective-C in Swift.

```
[emitterLayer setValue:@ (scale) forKeyPath:@"emitterCells.cell.emitterCells.childCell.scale"];
```

I have tried the following in Swift:

```
emitterLayer.setValue (scale), forKey: "emitterCells.cell.emitterCells.childCell.scale")
```

However this does not change the value as it would in objective-C

Does this work in Swift or do I need to refactor this to work differently to achieve the same result?

Comment: Is `scale` a value type?  Wrap it in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: `forKey` vs. `forKeyPath` ?

Comment: This is KVC, not KVO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but the syntax would be

```
emitterKayer.setValue(scale, 
  forKeyPath:  "emitterCells.cell.emitterCells.childCell.scale")
```